# global name 'request' is not defined: overriding form_valid

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I have an UpdateView which I am overriding the form_valid method. For some reason 'request' is shown as being not defined within the overridden method. Here is the full class:

```
 class UpdateTopic(UpdateView):
        model = Post
        slug_field = 'pk'
        slug_url_kwarg = 'pk'
        form_class = CommentForm
        template_name = "forums/update_topic.html"

        def form_valid(self, form): 
            user = self.request.user 
            rep = self.request.user.player.get_rep_total

            # protect the system against url input attacks
            if user == self.object.user or rep >=2500:
                self.object = form.save(commit=False)
                self.object.updated_by = self.request.user 
                self.object.save()
                messages.add_message(request, message.SUCCESS, "<strong>Success:</strong> The comment was edited successfully!")
            else:
                messages.add_message(request, message.ERROR, "<strong>Failed:</strong> You don't have the access level to edit that post!")
```

The problem is the line `messages.add_message(request, message.SUCCESS, "<strong>Success:</strong> The comment was edited successfully!")`
It seems like the `request` is out of scope some how. Why is it doing this? Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: It should be `self.request` and not `request`.

Comment: @limelights perhaps you could post that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `self.request` and not `request`.

```
messages.add_message(self.request, message.ERROR, "...")
```

Comment: I tried this earlier. Now I receive the error: global name 'message' is not defined.

Comment: Yeah, the enum you're using `message.ERROR` isn't defined so you probably forgot to import it.

Comment: I have imported messages: from django.contrib import messages. I need to import 'message' as well? I thought it was just part of the method 'add_message'

Comment: No, you have to import it. `from django.contrib.messages import constants as message`.