# request v self.request in Django

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I was just helped by the answer found here: [global name 'request' is not defined: overriding form_valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27854814/global-name-request-is-not-defined-overriding-form-valid) but that left me asking another question:

When do you use just request, and when do you have to use self.request - and why? The example I see in the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#dynamic-filtering don't use either request or self.request in the examples. Now maybe that's because it is a class based view, but I don't think I'm alone in getting the syntax and usage of cbv v generic v functional mixed up.

**UPDATE**

**My code**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView
from essell.models import Code

class CodeListView(ListView):
model = Code
template_name='statute.html'

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(CodeListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    return context
```

**from the docs**

```
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
from django.utils import timezone

from articles.models import Article

class ArticleListView(ListView):

model = Article

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(ArticleListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['now'] = timezone.now()
    return context
```

**MY CURRENT ERRORS**

TypeError at /us/constitution

cannot convert dictionary update sequence element #0 to a sequence

```
class CodeListView(ListView):
    model = Code
    template_name='statute.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    #context = super(CodeListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context = {'object_list':object_list}
    return context
```

NameError at /us/constitution

global name 'object_list' is not defined

from the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/
"This template will be rendered against a context containing a variable called object_list that contains all the publisher objects. A very simple template might look like the following:"

```
class CodeListView(ListView):
model = Code
template_name='statute.html'

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
context = super(CodeListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
context = {'object_list':object_list}
return context
```

global name 'object_list' is not defined

Comment: The docs page you link to clearly mentions the possible use of `self.request.user` in the text itself. In any case it is very unclear what you are asking. If you have problems with actual code, you should post it.

Comment: I posted a different but closely related question. I was going to delete this one but got a warning not to. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35584699/context-and-class-based-views-in-django

Answer (score 1):

Like anything else in Python, any variable you reference must already exist in your current context.

Originally, Django views were simply functions that took as their first argument the `request` variable. Presumably, if you're writing old-style views, whatever you define as your first variable (e.g. `def view_name(request, ...)`) will be where the request is provided.

If you're using class-based views, then your views are member functions, so by convention their first argument will be `self`, e.g. `def view_name(self, request, ...)`. In this case, refer to the Django documentation regarding which arguments are provided to which functions depending on which view you're subclassing.

Comment: If you search for self.request in the docs, the page I cited is one of only two hits you will get, and on that page self.request is not in the example view code. I just don't think the docs are very clear here, at least to those of us without a ton of experience already. And I probably spoke too soon when I said I was helped by the prior SO q&a. As soon as I changed from  request to self.request, I got a new error: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Comment: It's entirely understandable that the docs may not be clear enough. However, to really understand your issue, I'd need to see the code that's causing you problems. Please update your question with the relevant view code.